# mouse actions for SVG in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, svg

If I embed an SVG into a HTML page, then users can click on words in the SVG (that are included as text).

Is it possible (via JavaScript or similar) to find out which text element a user clicked on?

So e.g. if I have something like

```
<text class='f53' x='393.439815' y='162.22991'>EA</text>
```

to determine if the user clicked on this?

Comment: It is trivially possible by handling it exactly like regular HTML. https://jsfiddle.net/nqcgo4dm/ Can you clarify what exactly you mean by "find out which text element"? Would the text itself for instance be enough? Like "EA"?

Comment: @ChrisG Sorry, Chris, I did not know that. The text itself would not be enough, I also need the element itself because there could be multiple instances of the text `EA` in the document which would trigger different actions.

Comment: Like my fiddle shows, `this` inside the click handler references the clicked element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can determine on which element the action was performed like this:

```
const svg = document.querySelectorAll(".svg ");
svg.addEventListener('click', e => {
   if(e.target.classList.contains("f53")) {
    ...
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you , but up to now the classes are only used to set the font, so a lot of text elements share the same class. Do I need to define a unique class for each element, or is there another way?

Comment: yes, you can add an additional class or ID to the necessary elements